# MongoClient Parser Error: Unhandled Rejection (TypeError)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

I have followed MongoDB's get started guide and got the connect string & code from the 'Clusters' page with node.js driver version 3+, which looks like follows:

```
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';

const uri = "mongodb+srv://myname:mypassword@somecluster.mongodb.net/admin?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
    return;
  }
  // do something
});
```

All looks fine to me, put into react (I suppose this doesn't make any difference), and run the app. The url parser runs into an error:

`"Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined"`

which locates to the srv line in this function in mongodb's source file url_parser:

```
function matchesParentDomain(srvAddress, parentDomain) {
  const regex = /^.*?\./;
  >>> error here >>> const srv = ".".concat(srvAddress.replace(regex, ''));
  const parent = ".".concat(parentDomain.replace(regex, ''));
  return srv.endsWith(parent);
}
```

I suppose either i've made some terrible noob mistake or there's something wrong with the url parser?

My user name and password do not contain special chars, just normal alphanumerical charaters. I've also tried to set the username/password in the options:

```
userNewUrlParser: true,
auth: {
  user: 'myusername',
  password: 'mypassword'
}
```

same error :(

My `mongodb` version is `3.3.2`, which looks like it's the latest version as of today.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: There is no problem with the driver code. The error is simply throwing there since the provided URI is invalid. Literally give it exactly the same string as supplied from the Atals connect screen. Of course `<password>` will not be correct, but anything that gets up to Auth Failed will at least verify your platform. If not, include the node version and any other stack in use. Because `import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';` is not valid for NodeJS in any version without a transpiler in between

Comment: Thanks Neil, that's it i think - it's not supposed to be used in front end JS but has to be run in nodeJS server side. I'll give it a go later :)